# ARM, GNU assembler: how to pass "array" arguments to execve()?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, shellcode, execve

I was writing a simple shellcode that would call `execve()` for an ARM platform (Linux on Raspberry PI) and got stuck with the second argument to `execve`. As per [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve):

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

Which totally cuts it for me if I call `execve("/bin/sh", {NULL}, {NULL});` (from the assembly standpoint):

```
.data

.section .rodata

.command:
        .string "/bin/sh"

.text

.globl _start

_start: 
        mov r7, #11
        ldr r0, =.command
        eor r1, r1 @ temporarily forget about argv
        eor r2, r2 @ don't mind envp too
        svc #0

        mov r7, #1
        eor r0, r0
        svc #0
```

The assembly above compiles nicely and evokes a shell when run on my test machine that has true `/bin/sh`. However, all my trouble is that on the particular target box **there's no `/bin/sh`** per se, but only a symlink to `busybox` which necessitates me to execute something like `execve("/bin/busybox", {"/bin/busybox", "sh", NULL}, {NULL})`.

As to what I understand, arrays are continuous in memory, so all I have to do is to allocate bytes in memory in a continuous manner and then feed pointer to the beginning of what I deem as such "array". With that in mind I tried to the following:

```
.data

.section .rodata

.command:
        .string "/bin/busybox"

.args:  
        .ascii "/bin/busybox\0"
        .ascii "sh\0"
        .ascii "\0"

.text

.globl _start

_start: 
        mov r7, #11
        ldr r0, =.command
        ldr r1, =.args
        eor r2, r2
        svc #0

        mov r7, #1
        eor r0, r0
        svc #0
```

however with no success. Tried to play around with bytes and just create a series of bytes with null bytes filled to align to 4 bytes, which also didn't work. If the `.args` label looks like this:

```
.args:  
        .ascii "/bin/sh\0"
        .ascii "-c\0\0\0"
        .ascii "ls\0\0\0"
        .ascii "\0\0\0\0"
```

then `strace` of the program being executed is as below:

```
$ strace ./shell
execve("./shell", ["./shell"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
dup2(0, 4)                              = 4
dup2(1, 4)                              = 4
dup2(2, 4)                              = 4
execve("/bin/sh", [0x6e69622f, 0x68732f, 0x632d, 0x736c00], [/* 0 vars */]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

(Trying to execute `/bin/sh -c ls` first on the testing machine before coding for `/bin/busybox sh`).

I ran a similar C program and then debugged it to see how it's done. It appears the location that's passed to `r1` contains a bunch of pointers to strings and then, naturally, 0x00:

```
(gdb) x/4xw 0xbefff764
0xbefff764:     0x000105d0      0x000105d8      0x000105dc      0x00000000

... snip ...

(gdb) p argv
$3 = {0x105d0 "/bin/sh", 0x105d8 "-c", 0x105dc "ls", 0x0}
```

**Question**
Now that I figured out how memory is laid out, how do I prepare such layout in assembly and correctly pass the second parameter to `execve()` as an "array" in ARM assembly parlance?

Comment: Label each of your arguments and create an array of those labels and pass the address to that. That's how C string arrays work (`char**` type).

Comment: @Jester That's what I just realized I could do in assembly by looking at some sources. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gosh, I just came up with this... Several hours of fiddling around and then 2 minutes after posting my own question an answer hit me... Rubber duck debugging works.

```
.data

.section .rodata

command:
        .string "/bin/sh"

arg0:  
        .string "/bin/sh"

arg1:  
        .string "-c"

arg2:  
        .string "ls"

args:  
        .word arg0
        .word arg1
        .word arg2
        .word 0

.text

.globl _start

_start: 
        mov r7, #11
        ldr r0, =command
        ldr r1, =args
        eor r2, r2
        svc #0

        mov r7, #1
        eor r0, r0
        svc #0
```

Comment: The `.ascii "\0\0\0\0"` is a funny way to say `.word 0` :) Also, it's not a good idea to use symbols starting with a dot (`.`) as they can be confused with directives.

Comment: @Jester yeah it is, the code is a mess when fiddling with something so initially it was just a marker for me to inspect memory then I added zeros. I will brush this up later on.

Comment: For C strings, you might also find the `.asciz` directive handier than manually terminating everything.

Comment: @Notlikethat I'm busy with shellcode and particularly interested in the raw bytes than anything so I explicitly state the null bytes. Gotta rid those when adjusting the shellcode anyway. I guess the assembly above is just to explain my issue better. My local version is far from the one above (=

Comment: what if I want to execve the arguments the program was invoked with?

Comment: like ./myexec /bin/sh
how do I put the arguments of "myexec" into the execve?

Comment: @Zibri by pointing at the array just like `ldr r1, =args` does

Comment: what I mean is.. let's say this command is called execsh... and I invole it as ./execsh cat /home/test.txt       how can I use execve inside "execsh" to execute what I passed to it?

Comment: @Zibri oh I see. Command line arguments will be on the stack when your program starts. I believe you're looking for something like https://pastebin.com/MAA0NFsK (also check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtFs1yBVinc)

Comment: yes. so they are on the stack and must be "pop"ed ... ok

Answer (score 1):

You can use stack pointer to pass parameters. When program is started, first argument (arg[1]) will be in sp+8.

shell.s:

```
    .text
    .globl _start
    _start: 
        .code 32
            add r3,pc,#1
            bx r3
        .code 16
            ldr r0, [sp, #8] @ load argv[1] to r0
            add r1, sp, #8   @ set &argv[1] to r1
            eor r2, r2       @ set NULL to r2
            mov r7, #11
            svc #1
```

This code does same as next c code:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    execve(argv[1], &argv[1], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Third parameter is envp, it can be set to NULL.

To start /bin/sh:

```
shell /bin/sh
```

I hope this helps someone

Comment: For future readers, `eor r2, r2` is only a good idea in shellcode for avoiding a `0` byte in the machine code.  Unlike x86, the efficient way to zero a register is `mov r2, #0`.  (Just in case anyone was wondering if it's a good idea in general on ARM: it isn't.)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you commented the code, e.g. the `ldr` is loading `argv[1]`, a pointer to `"/bin/sh"`.  And `r1` gets a pointer to the whole `argv[]` array.  And Linux supports `envp=NULL` as being the same as `envp=`pointer to NULL.